# How can I find multiple match groups in a section of a file with python and regex?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to using python and regex to parse through a php config file and determine what plugins are enabled (1) or disabled (0). In the php file there is a plugins section and I only want to return data from that section. The problem is that I don't know how to just look at that plugins section from the file. I am currently using python's findall to try and solve this.

```php
<?php
return [
    'plugins' => [
        'Store' => 1,
        'Directory' => 1,
        'Theme' => 0
    ],
    'stores' => [
        'internal' => [
            '1' => [
                'id' => 0,
                'sort_order' => 0,
                'group_id' => 0
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'themes' => [
        'default' => [
            'id' => 1,
            'path' => 'var/www/html/themes'
        ]
    ]
];
```

Here is the code I am using to try and parse the data

```py
f = open("config.php","r")
contents = f.read()
f.close()

data = re.findall(r"'(\w+)'.+?(1|0)[,\n]+?",contents)
print(data)
```

When I run the python code I am getting

```
[('Store', '1'), ('Directory', '1'), ('Theme', '0'), ('id', '0'), ('sort_order', '0'), ('group_id', '0'), ('id', '1')]
```

How can I get this result with my python/regex code?

```
[('Store', '1'), ('Directory', '1'), ('Theme', '0')]
```

(Only the data from this section of the file)

```php
    'plugins' => [
        'Store' => 1,
        'Directory' => 1,
        'Theme' => 0
    ],
```

Comment: This feels pretty hacky--is there no way to `json_encode()` on the PHP side and `json.load()` on Python?

Comment: It is ok if it is hacky, I am only updating a google sheet with the data and the google sheet will only be used by a couple people. Plus gives me a reason to learn a little Python.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree--there is probably a very simple solution for this that's safe and reliable. If you can provide the exact requirements, that'd be much better than [presuppoing a solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), regardless of the scale of the project. Stack Overflow is about creating a repository of answers that are robust--there are other people that might be looking to do the same thing as you. So, even if you can hack parsing a PHP config file with regex, that's likely a poor general solution for the rest of the community.

Comment: Fair enough... Not sure I should update my original question or put it here... So I don't confuse people I will put it here. I am trying to read a php config file and extract what plugins that are disabled/enabled and store that in a google sheet (There will be a lot more then 3). The plugins are installed with composer, so I will also be storing the path to those plugin files and pull the dependents from the composer.json file of each of the plugins. I am storing this all in a google sheet so we have a place that we can easily view the status and dependents lists of the plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is most likely a better way, but this works well.

First isolate the `plugins` section with a regex:

```py
isolated = re.search(r"'plugins' => \[((\n|.)*?)\]", contents).group(1)
```

Next run the regex you have already wrote:

```py
data = re.findall(r"'(\w+)'.+?(1|0)[,\n]+?", isolated)
print(data)
# [('Store', '1'), ('Directory', '1'), ('Theme', '0')]
```

Comment: There might be a better way, but this does work and returns exactly the data I want. Thank you.